# UIButton title text color change

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIButton in a custom UIView. In the view, I have a function `setDisabled:(BOOL)disabled` which is called when I want to change the appearance of the UIView.

```
\\ Method 1
- (void) setDisabled:(BOOL)disabled
{
   myUIButton.titleLabel.textColor = disabled ? [UIColor systemGrayColor] : [UIColor systemBlueColor];
}
```

```
\\ Method 2
- (void) setDisabled:(BOOL)disabled
{
   [myUIButton setTitleColor: disabled ? [UIColor systemGrayColor] : [UIColor systemBlueColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I have used this UIView for cells in UITable view. Using **Method 1**, the change is not immediately reflected (reflected when i scroll through UITableView) whereas using **Method 2**, the color change is immediately reflected. In [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel) apple documentation, it is mentioned to not use **Method 1**. However I could not find the reason. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Prefer indeed method 2, but the issue is that cells are reused. So, where is called that method?

Comment: It is very obvious that `myUIButton.titleLabel` return u the color not sets the color.... To set button title color you need to use second method `myUIButton setTitleColor`

Comment: @Larme I call the method when initialising the table view.

Comment: @Kudos myUIButton.titleLabel also sets the color as after scrolling the table view, the color is changed.

Comment: Cells are reused, you need to show more code.

Answer (score 0):

Do ***NOT*** use "Method 1" ...

UIKit controls - such as `UIButton` - have a lot of code that does work "behind the scenes."

For example, if your button has a normal color of Red, and a Highlighted color of LightGray, and then you execute:

```
myUIButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor systemBlueColor];
```

The button itself *does not know* that you did that. It still has Red as its normal color property.

As soon as UIKit updates that button - a tap or a layout change, etc - the text color will be set back to the normal color property.